# Change environment for SharePoint list forms power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I am creating SharePoint list form in power app however the environment is personal one.

Is there any way to change the environment for SharePoint list forms power app to be created in other environment ( example production)

I don’t want to change the default environment as it may impact all users in that tenant.

If someone has created SharePoint list form in default environment ( personal ) so does that means if that user leave the company , the list form binded to that environment will not work anymore ? As his account will get disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rob for the reference. If suppose my default environment is personal for SharePoint list forms and in further I leave that company. Does this means list form that was created in my personal environment will also not work ?

Comment: 1. There is no such thing as "your" default environment. The tenant has a default environment that can be accessed by all makers. 2. Tenant admins can assign new owners to apps if the current owner leaves the company

Comment: I meant “personal environment “ that is set as default at organisation level so all users have their own personal environment

Comment: But I'm not sure how your personal environment applies to the question. The customized list forms are being created in the tenant's default environment, not in your personal environment, correct?

Comment: What I understand is customised list forms are created in default environment whatever the default environment is set by tennat admins. If default env is personal that means whatever list forms I create will be in that default personal environment. This environment is use for personal learning stuff as per tennat admins in my company, not to develop anything for end users.

Comment: No, each tenant has an environment known as the default environment. This is the same for all users. When any user in the tenant creates custom SharePoint list forms, they go into this environment.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/environments-overview#the-default-environment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140201/discussion-between-saira-and-rob-windsor).

Comment: Thank you Rob for your detailed answers.